# Query for selecting two different table having same columns

Tags: sql

I want to execute two queries having same number of columns. Here is my query, please help me to get the result:

```
SELECT  A.* 
FROM (SELECT * 
      FROM yh5lw_onlinecourse 
      WHERE state = 1 
      ORDER BY id DESC) A 
union 
SELECT A1.* 
FROM (SELECT * 
      FROM yh5lw_practicetest 
      WHERE state = 1 
      ORDER BY id DESC) A1
```

Comment: You should take care about the datatype of those columns, and also avoid using * in unions.

Comment: you are sure they have the same columns? I doubt that. Probably both tables `SHARE` some columns but have some extra, and that is probably what gets you an error, because `SELECT *` will get all columns and column lists for both tables differ, try selecting your column list explicitly by naming all of them that you need.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT A.id as id, A.field1 as outputname1, A.field2 as outputname2, ... and so on 
  FROM yh5lw_onlinecourse A
  WHERE state = 1 
  UNION
  SELECT A1.*
  FROM yh5lw_practicetest A1
  WHERE state = 1) myUnion
order by myUnion.id DESC
```

Pay attention:

If you use UNION instead UNION ALL you discard all duplicated value-

First query must have alias because in this way you named yuor output table. The second query (after UNION) can use * wildcard (but the number of fields must be the same)